# i dont want to see white selection in vs code. how?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, whitespace

How do I remove the white selection from empty spaces of visual studio code mac?

[image: Screen shot of VSCode showing erroneous white rectangles in code areas]

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a bug in VS Code MacOS version, which is currently an [open issue in VS Code GitHub repo](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/152816).

You can try out [this solution](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/152816#issuecomment-1179157443):

1. Open `~/.vscode/argv.json` file
2. Comment out `"disable-color-correct-rendering": true`
3. Restart VS Code